# Подсчет суммы строк в таблице

Tags: sql-server, sql

В таблице значения 1,2,2,1 посчитать сумму из строк 1+1, 2+2 SQL

```
Таблица Стоимость 
Код ОС | Первоначальная стоимость | Текущая (первоначальная + сумма обслуживания) 
_________________________________________________________________________ 
1      | 200                      | первоначальная + СуммаОбслуживания где 
                                    встречается код ос ) 100+10 
2      | 100                      | первоначальная + СуммаОбслуживания где 
                                    встречаются код ос ) 30+20

Таблица Обслуживание 
Код Обслуживания| Код ОС |СуммаОбслуживания 
_________________________________________ 
1               | 1      | 100 
2               | 2      | 30 
3               | 2      | 20 
4               | 1      | 10
```

ТаблицаСтоимость.текущая = ТаблицаСтоимость.первоначальная + суммаОбслуживания

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Стоимость
SET Текущая = ПервоначальнаяСтоимость + СтоимостьОбслуживания.Сумма
FROM Стоимость INNER JOIN
    (SELECT КодОС, SUM(СуммаОбслуживания) AS Сумма
     FROM Обслуживание
     GROUP BY КодОС) AS СтоимостьОбслуживания
ON Стоимость.КодОС = СтоимостьОбслуживания.КодОС
```

---

Судя по всему, это учебное задание, поэтому здесь такой вариант решения вполне подойдёт. В реальном приложении было бы нерационально всегда пересчитывать это значение для каждой записи.

Answer (score 1):

```
select @summa = sum(Обслуживание.суммаобслуживания)...
```

Ну и переменной нельзя присвоить набор значений. :-)